# Pause execution until button press

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4, wait

I have a QStackedWidget.  In the logic (not the UI) I am trying to change pages and wait there until a button on that page is pressed (basically an OK/Cancel). I pass the UI to the function in the class.

Something like this:

```
def func1(self, window):
    window.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(4)
    while True:
        window.btn_OK.clicked.connect(self.OK_func)
        window.btn_Cancel.clicked.connect(self.Can_func)

def OK_func(self, window):
    do_something
    window.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(3)
    break

def Can_func(self, window):
    window.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(3)
    break

for i in range(5):
    #stuff
    func1(window)  #this is where I want to pause
    #other stuff
```

Now I know that I can't break with the function like that or pass the window variable through connect, but I hope that makes my point clearly enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple way to do this is to process pending events inside the loop (so the UI remains responsive), and set/unset an internal flag to control starting and stopping of the loop.

The following demo script shows a basic implementation of this idea:

```
import time
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.buttonStart = QtGui.QPushButton('Start', self)
        self.buttonStart.clicked.connect(self.handleStart)
        layout.addWidget(self.buttonStart)
        self.buttonStop = QtGui.QPushButton('Stop', self)
        self.buttonStop.clicked.connect(self.handleStop)
        layout.addWidget(self.buttonStop)
        self._running = False

    def handleStart(self):
        self.buttonStart.setDisabled(True)
        self._running = True
        while self._running:
            self.label.setText(str(time.clock()))
            QtGui.qApp.processEvents()
            time.sleep(0.05)
        self.buttonStart.setDisabled(False)

    def handleStop(self):
        self._running = False

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(500, 300, 200, 100)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: This is gorgeous.  Absolutely what I was looking for, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `while` and `break`.

```
def func1(self, window):
    window.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(4)
    window.btn_OK.clicked.connect(self.OK_func)
    window.btn_Cancel.clicked.connect(self.Can_func)

def OK_func(self, window):
    # do_something
    window.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(3)

def Can_func(self, window):
    window.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(3)
```

Comment: That doesn't pause execution.

Comment: @Faller, what part should be paused? `OK_func` ? `Can_func`? some other parts?

Comment: It should be paused during func1 after the "setCurrentIndex" until it gets input from OK_func or Can_func

Comment: @Faller, If there is infinite loop, `OK_func`, `Can_func` can never be called. And callback will be registered multiple times.  And more importantly it freeze the GUI.

Comment: @Faller, Is there anything after the `while` loop?

Comment: @Faller, If there's anything (let's call it X) after the while loop. Split X part into another function and call X from `OK_func` and `Can_func`.

Comment: No there's nothing after the while loop.  I don't even need the while loop.  It's just the only way I could think of to actually pause execution.

Comment: @Faller, I don't understand what you want to pause.

Comment: This func1 is called inside a for loop.  There are things that happen before and after it.  I simply want to be able to call it and it pause all execution.  My apologies for the lack of clarity.

Comment: @Faller, Please update your question with the code that call `func1`.

Comment: @Faller, Could you post minimal runnable code that show your problem?